# Splitindex not working with hyper ref

Tags: hyperref, splitidx

I have some problem with the compatibility o between the split-index package and the hyperref package: the number printed in the table of contents is right, but clicking on it takes to the wrong page...
Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[oneside]{report}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,
left=2cm,right=2cm} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=numeric %,citestyle=verbose-trad1
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{luacode}    
%\usepackage{calendar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\lhead{}
\chead{\thepage}
\rhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}

%\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage[useindex]{splitidx} % ... and the splitidx package
\makeindex
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}




%\newcommand{\nuovoindice}[2]{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1 #2}\printindex[#1#2]}
\usepackage[pageanchor=true, hyperindex = true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\newindex[Ottobre 2018]{Ottobre2018}
\newindex[Novembre 2018]{Novembre2018}
\newindex[Dicembre 2018]{Dicembre2018}
\newindex[Gennaio 2019]{Gennaio2019}
\newindex[Febbraio 2019]{Febbrario2019}
\newindex[Marzo 2019]{Marzo2019}
\newindex[Aprile 2019]{Aprile2019}
\newindex[Maggio 2019]{Maggio2019}
\newindex[Giugno 2019]{Giugno2019}
\newindex[Luglio 2019]{Luglio2019}
\newindex[Agosto 2019]{Agosto2019}
\newindex[Settembre 2019]{Settembre2019}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
foo
\index[Ottobre2018]{foo}
\index[Novembre2018]{foo}
\index[Dicembre2018]{foo}
\index[Gennaio2019]{foo}
\index[Febbraio2019]{foo}
\index[Marzo2019]{foo}

\printindex*
\end{document}
```